# Load an image from https URL with login in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, https, ssl-certificate

in Unity3d Im trying to load a gif image from a https website but when i open the image link in the browser it opens a different website to login in it (username, password) , after i login it direct me back to the original image url then it shows the image, i wanna do all these steps in the code and then apply this image on plane as a texture.

Please i need a help

Answer (score 0):

Why not host the image on your own server? There are plenty of free options like,[000webhost](http://000webhost.com).Then you can use the [WWW](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWW.html) Unity class.It saves you a lot of hassle.
Here's some sample code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class ImageLoader : MonoBehaviour()
{
  string url = "https://example.com/image.jpeg";
  IEnumerator Start(){

    WWW img = new WWW(url);
    yield return img;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = img.texture;
  }
}
```

Comment: there are alot of images i wanna load in the same way , i cant take all of them

Comment: yes you can,just attach the script to the object with a renderer and you'll be good to go

Comment: man im talking about load the images from the https website , not how to load the image on texture

Comment: Like a object with a sprite renderer